# Canonical way to get a more specific lemma

Tags: isabelle, apply-script

Say I have a lemma `mylem: foo ?a = bar ?a`, and I need to apply it on a goal that has two occurrences of `foo`, e.g. `baz (foo (f p q)) (foo (g r s))`, but only at one of these positions. I know of two ways of doing that without having to write out all of `p`,`q`..., which can be complex expressions.

- Using `apply (subst mylem)` followed by an appropriate number (here, zero or one) of `back` commands.
- Using `apply (subst mylem[where a = 'foo x y', standard])`, where `x` and `y` are unbound names.

The use of `subst` here is just for demonstration; I really do want to modify the lemma, e.g. to use it with `rule` when there are multiple possible matches that I’d like to disambiguate this way.

Both approaches look like bad style to me. Is there a nicer way of achieving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `subst` which occurrence it should replace: `subst (i) mylem` unfolds `mylem` at the `i`-th matching occurrence. This saves you the `back` steps. You can also list multiple positions as in `subst (1 2) mylem`. If you want to unfold `mylem` in premises, use `subst (asm) (1 2) mylem`.

In general, I do not know a way to achieve what you want inside an `apply` script. On the theory level, you can use `lemmas` with the `for` clause to generalise over locally introduced variables:

```
lemmas mylem' = mylem[where a="f x y"] for x y
```

Inside a structured proof, you can do it explicitly like this:

```
{ fix x y note mylem[where a="f x y"] }
note mylem' = this
```

Comment: Ok, that works for subst. But what if the I want to apply the rule with, say, `rule` and there are multiple ways to unify it with the goal?

Comment: I didn’t know about `for` this way before. Can I use it in more positions than with `lemmas` and `interpret(ation)`?

Comment: You can use `for` with `theorems`, which is similar to `lemmas`; with `inductive` and `inductive_set` to fix parameters; and inside locale expressions as they occur in `interpret(ation)`, `sublocale`, and `locale ... = ... for ... +`.